# Django: set filter manager at runtime

Tags: python-3.x, django, database

My Django app stores the same sets of data for multiple different chat servers. Each model has a server as a ForeignKey to track which server the data is from. In my views.py, I have a bunch of manager/model functions like this:

```
def index(request)
   context = {
       'most_pinged': User.objects.get_most_pinged_user(),

       'top_emojis': Emojis.objects.get_top_emojis(user1),

       'top_channels': Channels.objects.order_by('-messages')[:10]
   }
```

etc.

The problem: I want to make it so that these functions only operate on the data of ONE server at a time, and filter out all of the data from other servers. I'd have to write a bunch of filters, like so:

```
def index(request, server_id):

   context = {
       'most_pinged':User.objects.get_most_pinged_user(from_server=server_id),

       'top_emojis': Emojis.objects.get_top_emojis(user1, from_server=server_id),

       'top_channels': Channels.objects.filter(server__id=server_id).order_by('-messages')
    }
```

Is there any way to make it so that instead of having to write a bunch of filters for my manager methods and such, I can just have `User/Emoji/Chnanel.objects` filter out all of the other server's data from the get-go? Managers can be used to filter data, but not dynamically like this (afaik). I'm willing to be flexible!